# Взлом пароля, почему  так произошло?

Tags: пароль, ubuntu

Здравствуйте! У меня стоит на ноуте Ubuntu 11.10, у меня стоял пароль, чтобы войти в систему, как моя жена могла обойти пароль, вошла в систему, просмотрела все, почту, историю и т.п., помогите, чтобы в дальнейшем у меня не было больше таких ситуаций.

Answer (score 1):

А может тут вообще чисто человеческий фактор.. вот знает тебя жена, как облупленного, как ты пароли генеришь знает, и мы уже знаем больше, чем должны, и лет тебе 31, и день рожденья у тебя 17-го июня ))

Comment: нет, мне 33 года, день рождение 18 февраля

Comment: ну, это было типо шутки, которую многие могли оценить ))Так вот.. все нижеизложенные варианты реальны, лучшим выходом всё-таки является шифрование хоум раздела и использование более криптостойкого пароля, чем <pre>[a-z]*[0-9]*</pre>

Answer (score 0):

примитивный мб был пароль?)

Comment: Это самый весомый аргумент. или жена у тебя линуксойдный хакер, а выглядит как обычная девушка :)

Comment: пароль был jura0170679

Answer (score 0):

Правильно говорит человек, что написал про пароль на груб.Н о и это не спасет от этого.И мея физический доступ к компу я приду, солью файл паролей через загруку лайв-сд. Потом скормлю джон риперу и через некоторое время он достанет мне твой пароль. Хочешь безопасности - читай http://www.opennet.ru/base/sec/linux_sec_guide.txt.html потом ставь шифрованую файловую систему, а дальше только твоя фантазия ограничит твои действия.

Хотя если жена так легко достала твой пароль - где-то он есть еще, кроме как в твоей голове.

Answer (score 0):

По-моему, забыли написать про sudo su. В бубунте пользователь по дефолту в группе sudo, надо у всех юзер-аккаунтов права на судо отобрать или выставить по уму. А так ещё можно загрузиться в однопользовательском режиме (передать ядру параметр single при загрузке) - пароль на груб от этого спасёт. При загрузке с лайвцд/юсб тоже не проблема вытащить или поменять /etc/shadow - как уже говорили, надо шифровать раздел. Это всё очевидные вещи, плюс надо помнить о физической стороне - может, пароль где-то записан или его легко подобрать - пароль должен быть случайным набором всех возможных символов, а не иметь вид <имя*родственника><дата*рождения>. Учите матчасть перед тем, как использовать Убунту, может, жена поможет )))

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант: Надо больше доверять жене, чтобы жена доверяла тебе.А вообще - ставь пароль на рута, сложный. И на юзверя меняй, слишком уж легкоподбираемый пароль.

Comment: Как мне на рут поставить пароль, подскажите, я немного не разобрался, киньте ссылку

Answer (score 0):

Утилита passwd без указания имени пользователя меняет пароль root, правда и запускать нужно  имея соответствующие права. Например так:User@linux$ sudo passwdType new password:Retype new password:Done!